# HTML5 Canvas drawing is layering a new path over the existing path at each new point. Why?

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

This is hard to explain so I created a JS Fiddle to show what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/dGdxS/ - (Webkit only) Just mouse over the canvas to draw - you may need to click around

I noticed the performance of the canvas was not what I expected, and when I set the line alpha I think I see why.

It looks like every new point I add to the drawing it is layering a completely new line over the previous line. The stroke alpha is set to 1%, and when you draw the older areas of the stroke begin to darken as the layers build up.

I assume I am doing something wrong. Do I need to clear the canvas before drawing to it at each new point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never call `ctx.closePath();`, so it will redraw the entire path from the beginning each time.

So you really want something similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGdxS/7/

Comment: Doesn't this just draw individual non-connected segments, and not actually extend the initial line?

Comment: It does. But when you just repeat ctx.lineTo it extend current line and ctx.stroke() will color it again and again (this is the point of your problem). Currently i dont see any solution for this :/

Comment: Yes. You can extend the initial line if you want by using your original code and adding `ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);`, thus clearing the canvas before every mouse move. This makes operations afterwards tricky, though, because assuming you want more than just one stroke on the canvas, you'll have to clear-canvas, redraw all the old stuff, then draw the latest stroke each time. This may get heavy on performance, and the onus is on you to remember each object drawn previously.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it there are some good ways to improve the performance of such an app. Let me know if it is actually the case and I'll explain them.

Comment: Just found that calling `ctx.beginPath();` will clear the current subpath without closing the shape.

Comment: Hi @SimonSarris , we would love some ideas on how to improve performance in app like this ... or if anyone has ideas on how to smooth user lines in HTML5 from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895494/smooth-jagged-lines-drawn-by-user-in-html5-canvas-app

Comment: Calling closePath won't solve the problem. closePath merely extends the current subpath to its starting point and begins a new *subpath*. There will still be one big path that continues to grow and grow...

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 canvas does *not come* with an `endPath` method, but instead you can call `context.beginPath()` again to close the current path and begin a new one.

This is as opposed to calling `context.closePath()`, which will actually draw a line to the beginning of the current path, but not *end* it. If you were to draw again, the pen will simply continue drawing from that same point that closed the path. See this excellent [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807551/445210) for more details and explanations.