# Sharp edges while drawing in canvas using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I'm practicing how to use and draw in canvas using jquery but I'm getting sharp edges while moving my mouse(as shown below) is there any way on getting smooth edges while drawing in jquery? Help is appreciated and thanks in advance :).

**jquery**

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
// var points;
var brush = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  color: '#000000',
  size: 4,
  down: false
};

var strokes = []; // for storing prev strokes
var currentStroke = null // current stroke

function redraw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  for (var i = 0; i < strokes.length; i++) {
    var s = strokes[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = s.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = s.size;
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x, s.points[0].y);
    for (var j = 0; j < s.points.length; j++) {
      var p = s.points[j];
      ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}

function init() {
  canvas = $('#draw');
  canvas.attr({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  })
  ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  // console.log(ctx,"this is ctx");


  // function mouseEvent(e) {
  //     console.log(e.pageX,"Xval");
  //     console.log(e.pageY,"Yval");
  //     brush.x = e.pageX;
  //     brush.y = e.pageY;

  //     currentStroke.points.push({
  //         x: brush.x,
  //         y: brush.y
  //     });

  //     redraw();

  // }

  // adding mouseEvent listerners,
  canvas.mousedown(function(e) {

    brush.down = true;

    brush.x = e.pageX;
    brush.y = e.pageY;


    currentStroke = {
      color: brush.color,
      size: brush.size,
      points: []
    };

    currentStroke.points.push({
      x: brush.x,
      y: brush.y
    })

    redraw();
    // mouseEvent(e);
    //now we have to push this to strokes which keeps track of preveous data

    strokes.push(currentStroke);




  }).mouseup(function(e) {
    brush.down = false;

    brush.x = e.pageX;
    brush.y = e.pageY;

    currentStroke.points.push({
      x: brush.x,
      y: brush.y
    })

    currentStroke = null;
    redraw();


  }).mousemove(function(e) {

    if (brush.down) {
      brush.x = e.pageX;
      brush.y = e.pageY;

      currentStroke.points.push({
        x: brush.x,
        y: brush.y
      });

      redraw();

    }
  })

  $('#save-btn').click(function() {
    window.open(canvas[0].toDataURL());
  });

  $('#undo-btn').click(function() {
    strokes.pop();
    redraw();
  });
  $('#color-picker').on('input', function() {
    brush.color = this.value;
  });
  $('#brush-size').on('input', function() {
    brush.size = this.value;
  })

}







$(init); //... (when document is ready)(calling the function)
```

The following is my output drawing the edges are sharp. the above one is the code I'm practicing. I used Jquery, Html Canvas.
[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKgle.png)

Comment: Firstly, there are lots of good articles on that topic and one of those is another Stack similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895494/smooth-jagged-lines-drawn-by-user-in-html5-canvas-app

Comment: Hey.. thanks a lot for that @Twisty ! :).... I have an other doubt how do I make a new page without losing the old page?... thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure. I am guessing you'd want to collect all the data and save it someplace before creating a new page.